# Django : Manipulate Data in a generic.ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I wonder if it's possible to apply a rule on every record of a ListView
Example : get from a model a value in grams and create a new var containing the kg value if the gram value > 1000

I have tried with get_object but it only works for ViewDetail

Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
class ViewBsin(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'browser/bsin.html'
context_object_name = 'gtin_list'
model = Gtin
...
def get_object(self):
    # Call the superclass
    object = super(ViewBsin, self).get_object()
    # Add new data
    if object.M_G and object.M_G >= 1000:
        object.M_KG = object.M_G / 1000
    if object.M_ML and object.M_ML >= 1000:
        object.M_L = object.M_ML / 1000
    object.save()
    # Return the object
return object
```

Comment: thx ! but i have to store this data because the unit is Gram (g) that I want to display as KiloGram (Kg) .. because 1 Kg = 1000 g ;) ... the only way to do it is to divide into the template ?? but there's no way to devide into the template :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `get_queryset` and loop through the querysets, updating the objects. You shouldn't call save() because this would update the database, and `ListView` should be read only.

```
class ViewBsin(generic.ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ViewBsin, self).get_queryset()
        for obj in queryset:
            if obj.M_G and obj.M_G >= 1000:
                obj.M_KG = obj.M_G / 1000
            # Make any other changes to the obj here
            # Don't save the obj to the database -- ListView should be read only
        return queryset
```

A different approach would be to write a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that converts grams to kilograms.

Then, in your template, instead of writing

```
{{ object.M_KG }}
```

You would do

```
{{ object.M_G|to_kg }}
```

If you have more custom logic, like 'display KG if g > 1000, otherwise display g', then this can all go in the template filter as well. This simplifies your templates, and keeps display logic out of the view.